# Extract First string in the sentence

Tags: r

U have a sentence where I need to extract the first even word. For example

```
  df <- ("This is not the sentence")
```

For the above sentence, I need "This" to be extracted because it is the first even word

Another example is

```
  df <- ("She is not going anywhere")
```

For the above sentence, I need "is" to be extracted because it is the first even word

Comment: Do you mean an even number of characters in the word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can write a function to do this. We split the string on whitespace count number of characters in each word and return the first even word.

```
extract_first_even_word <- function(text) {
   all_words <- strsplit(text, "\\s+")[[1]]
   all_words[which.max(nchar(all_words) %% 2 == 0)]
}
extract_first_even_word("This is not the sentence")
#[1] "This"

extract_first_even_word("She is not going anywhere")
#[1] "is"
```

Comment: perfect. But i tried this but missed to include \\s+ here, May I know what is it doing?

Comment: @DevP It is used to split on one or more space in the text, so it would also work if you have more than one spaces between words.